# How to make or create flipcards dynamically using javascript or jquery on clicking a button or link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made flipping cards which flip when you hover over them. However, i have made a link/button so that on clicking it a new flipcard will be created. Not being able to achieve this.....some help would be appreciated...also m new here !
Below is my html and css code for the flipcards:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#new").click(function() {
    $("card effect__hover").clone().insertAfter(thi);
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  background: url(index_bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.card:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.card:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.card.effect__ADD {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.card__front,
.card__back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.card__front,
.card__back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
.card__front {
  background-color: blue;
}
.card__back {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card.effect__hover:hover .card__front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card.effect__hover:hover .card__back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
.card.effect__ADD:hover .card__front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.card.effect__ADD:hover .card__back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
  transform: rotateX(0);
}
span > p {
  margin-top: 80px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Read</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
  <link href="read.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card effect__hover">
    <div class="card__front">
      <span class="card__text"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="card__back">
      <span class="card__text"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card effect__hover">
    <div class="card__front">
      <span class="card__text"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="card__back">
      <span class="card__text"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card effect__hover">
    <div class="card__front">
      <span class="card__text"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="card__back">
      <span class="card__text"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="" class="new">
    <div class="card effect__ADD">
      <div class="card__front">
        <span class="card__text"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <span class="card__text"><p>Add Your Story</p></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>


</body>

</html>
```

I would realy appreciate if it can be done in jquery

Comment: You have posted a lot of useless code for your question but you miss the only important one: your js code.

Comment: The js part is the problem actually ! if i want to add a flipcard dynamically on that page on the click of a button or link then what should be the js code for that..... i have tried creating divs and appyling styles but none of them worked as you can see the css code is divided into a lot of parts for the same effect.

Comment: SO is not a "write code for me" site. You can ask help for what is not working in the code you have written.

Comment: i have given the code below !! thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/p9zr3j54/2/), I've add an event listener to the `<a class="new">`  to pick it and then prevents its default action upon the event of clicking.. after that I cloned the first card element and inserted it right before the (add your story) link so that we always have that link at the bottom

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('.new').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
       $('.card').first().clone().insertBefore($('.new'));    
    });
});
```

```css
.card {
    margin:5px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.card:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.card:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.card.effect__ADD {
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.card__front, .card__back {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.card__front, .card__back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
.card__front {
    background-color:blue;
}
.card__back {
    background-color:orange;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card.effect__hover:hover .card__front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card.effect__hover:hover .card__back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
    transform: rotateY(0);
}
.card.effect__ADD:hover .card__front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.card.effect__ADD:hover .card__back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
    transform: rotateX(0);
}
span > p {
    margin-top: 80px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card effect__hover">
  <div class="card__front"> <span class="card__text"></span>

  </div>
  <div class="card__back"> <span class="card__text"></span>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card effect__hover">
  <div class="card__front"> <span class="card__text"></span>

  </div>
  <div class="card__back"> <span class="card__text"></span>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="card effect__hover">
  <div class="card__front"> <span class="card__text"></span>

  </div>
  <div class="card__back"> <span class="card__text"></span>

  </div>
</div>
<a href="" class="new">
  <div class="card effect__ADD">
    <div class="card__front">
      <span class="card__text"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="card__back">
      <span class="card__text"><p>Add Your Story</p></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

*Note that you might need to add margin to the flip card to make gaps between them*

***Update upon a comment:***

The messy arrangement of the flip cards is caused becaus:

1. In the `.card` css you have `float: left;`, remove this and add this line instead `display:inline-block;`, this will line them all up on the same line
2. in the `.card:nth-child(1)` css remove these two lines `margin-top: 100px;` and `margin-left: 100px;`, by doing this you will omit the unwanted gap before the first card.
   After doing above, the result you'll get is like in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7ce6cvj/)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I appreciate this effort, i am new here and will actively participate in all matters here....its awesome !! Thank You !

Comment: You welcome, I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Also there is one more problem, the divs which are added are so in a haphazard manner. They should align properly below the other flipcards and also leave out a bit of space from the left ! I have made the margin between them proper but unable to do this.

Comment: the margin thing you did only make little and even gaps between cards, the unlined arrangement of the divs was caused by some other properties, check the updated section in my answer for details